# IPv4Address.compressed meaning for ipaddress

Tags: python, ip-address

When I read the ipaddress docs:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address.compressed

When I read the `IPv4Address.compressed`, I find there is no explain for the `compressed`.

Who can tell me what is it mean ?

---

From the [source 
code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/ipaddress.py#L397), there is only `Return the shorthand version of the IP address as a string.` explain, I am not well understand the `shorthand version of the IP address`.

Comment: I would sort of expect it to omit optional zeros from 127.0.0.1 to produce 127.1 but it doesn't. Maybe it's more useful for IPv6 and included for orthogonality for IPv4.  I see it doing what this page describes for IPv6: https://networklessons.com/ipv6/shortening-ipv6-addresses/

Comment: @tripleee That makes sense, because the IPv4 object have many property for imitate IPv6 object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compressed` and `exploded` are properties defined by the base class [`ipaddress._IPAddressBase`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/ipaddress.py#L385), so every ip address instance has them. For IPv4 there is no difference between the two, as historically there was no need to have a shorter representation:

```
>>> i4 = ipaddress.IPv4Address("127.0.0.1")
>>> i4.exploded
'127.0.0.1'
>>> i4.compressed
'127.0.0.1'
```

The difference is with ipv6 addresses:

```
>>> i6 = ipaddress.IPv6Address("::1")
>>> i6.exploded
'0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001'
>>> i6.compressed
'::1'
```

Here leaving out groups of 0s is a big help for usability.

Since all addresses have both properties you don't need to care what type an address object is. If only `IPv6Address` objects had an `exploded` property it would be more cumbersome to use it when processing mixed address types.

Comment: It's not entirely true that there are no shortened versions of IPv4 addresses.  There are obscure notations which were once moderately widespread, but I suppose they ended up being abused as security holes more often than they were actually useful.

Comment: @tripleee At least there doesn't seem to have been enough need to write a RFC, or I haven't come across one. At least if you see an ip address in this form you tend to know what it is. I've once come across a log file with addresses in hex notation, took me some minutes to figure out what those ment.

Comment: You can still do stuff like `ping 134744072` on some platforms.

Comment: Quick googling turned up this: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-main-ipaddr-text-rep-02

Comment: @tripleee nice, didn't know that one. Seems even firefox accepts  addresses like http://2899908494 :)

Answer (score 2):

> I find there is no explain for the compressed

It's actually [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address.compressed) *together* with the **exploded** property:

> **compressed**
>
> **exploded**
>
> The string representation in dotted decimal notation. Leading zeroes are never included in the representation.
>
> As IPv4 does not define a shorthand notation for addresses with octets set to zero, these two attributes are always the same as
>   `str(addr)` for IPv4 addresses. Exposing these attributes makes it
>   easier to write display code that can handle both IPv4 and IPv6
>   addresses.

The property itself is [defined](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/ipaddress.py#L397) in the base class for both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses as follows:

```
@property
def compressed(self):
    """Return the shorthand version of the IP address as a string."""
    return str(self)
```

For an `IPv4Address` object `str(self)` would return a [string](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/ipaddress.py#L1163) in decimal-dot notation, e.g. `"192.168.0.1"`.

Comment: is there a example of it?  I am not very understand the `shorthand version of the IP address as a string`.